# Passing variables from ViewModel to View in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel

I have this ViewModel:

```
public DashboardViewModel(Dashboard dashboard)
        {
            HardwareType hwt = new HardwareType { HType = "PC" };
            IQueryable<Hardware> Pcs = db.Hardware.Where(h => h.HardwareType.Contains(hwt));

        }
```

I want to pass the Pcs variable to my view so I can iterate through it.  Here is my controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "ULS Computer Inventory Tracker";

            Dashboard dashboard = new Dashboard();
            var dashbaordViewModel = new DashboardViewModel(dashboard);

            return View(dashboardViewModel);
        }
```

And my view:

```
@{
    @model CIT.ViewModels.DashboardViewModel
}

...

 @foreach (var item in Pcs) {
    <li><a href="#" class="btn"><i class="icon-hdd"></i> @item.HardwareType</a></li>
 }
```

But I get an error that `Pcs` doesn't exist in the current context.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Pcs has to be public to be visible else where, is Pcs public? Fields/Properties are not public by default.

Comment: Can you address the error I'm getting in the answer below?

Answer (score 0):

As it exists right now Pcs is scoped as a variable that exists only in the constructor of the viewmodel so you need to expose the PCS variable as a member level variable to the ViewModel..

```
    public IEnumerable<Hardware> Pcs { get; set; }

    public DashboardViewModel(Dashboard dashboard)
    {
        HardwareType hwt = new HardwareType { HType = "PC" };
        Pcs = db.Hardware.Where(h => h.HardwareType.Contains(hwt));
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting an error that get and set don't exist in the current context

Comment: Sorry forgot the `public` access modifier in my original example, try with the updated example

Answer (score 0):

For the view to be able to access it, `Pcs` needs to be publicly accessible from the instance scope. Ideally this should be done via a public property:

```
Public IEnumerable<Hardware> Pcs {get; private set;}

public DashboardViewModel(Dashboard dashboard)
{
    HardwareType hwt = new HardwareType { HType = "PC" };
    this.Pcs = db.Hardware.Where(h => h.HardwareType.Contains(hwt));
}
```

Should also reference it via the model in the view:

```
@foreach (Hardware item in Model.Pcs)
```

Comment: I'm still get an error with get and set.  Also, I am getting errors with the VM name.

Comment: Had a stray equal sign after Pcs.

Comment: On the view, I think you'll need to use: `@foreach (Hardware item in model.Pcs)`. Not sure about the get/set issue - is it a runtime error, or a compilation error?

Comment: I fixed the get/set issue.  I am now getting an error that DashboardViewModel needs a return type.  But when I put one I get another error.

Comment: I'm getting an error `model` does not exist in the current context for `model.Pcs`

Comment: My bad - typo (no capitalisation) - should be `@foreach (Hardware item in Model.Pcs)`. Edited answer to fix.